# dynamically generate an attribute on an object, ruby, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given these params:

ex: 1

```
{:field => 'admin', :id => "1"}
```

ex: 2

```
{:field => 'client', :id => "1"}
```

ex: 3

```
{:field => 'partner', :id => "1"}
```

Is it possible, (and how of course) could i dynamically apply this to the `User` model such as:

controller

```
#note the field attribute is not a field
#the field attribute I'm trying to set above to what are given in the params hash

def update_user
    field = params[:field]
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.field = !@user.field
    @user.save(false)
    render :nothing => true
end
```

---

fyi

Why not just send a has with params and update the with `update_attributes(params[:user])`? Because the users attributes are protected and it's just easier to update a boolean this way.

Comment: Is `update_user` supposed to do anything with the local variable `field`?

Comment: the point of the `field` local variable is to dynamically generate the attribute that needs to be updated

Comment: Are the attributes like `admin` and `client` and are they in the db or just instance variables?

Comment: They are just an example of attributes on a `User` model.

Comment: I guess it is really confusing so I will update the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
@user = User.where("#{params[:field]} = ?", params[:id]).first if ["admin", "client", "partner"].include?(params[:field])
```

(The "include?" is a security check to prevent users from choosing some other field you don't want them to)

Comment: That's interesting. Not exactly what I was going for but opens other doors. BTW, I'm trying to set based on a dynamic attribute not find